# Relationship question?

Tags: custom-object, sharing, relationships

A company has a custom object named Warehouse. Each Warehouse record has a distinct record owner, and is related to a parent Account in Salesforce. Which kind of relationship would a developer use to relate the Account to Warehouse?

Pls explain..

Answer (score 2):

Because it has  a owner field it must be a stand alone object. Parent account i  assume will be a lookup field on the custom warehouse object.

You can verify the sharing settings of warehouse object by going to Setup --> Sharing settings and the warehouse object will be one of Public/Private and not 'Controlled by parent' which indicates this in the detail side of a master object